# If a DT is imaginary and odd, prove that it's coefficients are real and odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-series, signal-processing

I have discrete signal, $x[n]$ that is imaginary and odd. I want to prove that its coefficients are real and odd. First of all, is there an intuitive understanding by this? Second, I know the following pieces of information but I'm not sure how exactly to piece it together to prove it.

Since $x[n]$ is odd, we know that $x[n] = −x[−n]$. Also, $a_k = −a_{−k}$. Thus, $a_k$ is odd in $k$. Since x[n] is imaginary, $x[n] = −x^∗[n]$. And so we have $a_k = −a^*_{−k}$. How do I piece all this together to prove that the coefficients themselves are real and odd? I'm not sure what the end product should exactly look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You've found that $a_k=-a_{-k}$ (where negative indices are taken modulo $N$), and $a_k=-a^*_{-k}$. From this it follows that $a_{-k}=a^*_{-k}$, which can only be the case if the coefficients $a_k$ are real-valued. Combining this with $a_k=-a_{-k}$ gives the result that they are real-valued and odd.

Comment: OO, pfft, I can't believe I missed that connection. Thank you!